# How To Implement Auto Scrolling Video in React Native using JSX

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, autoscroll

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
 import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import {videos} from './data';

// code started creating state on every event which will be used 


    enter center export default function App() {

  const [pitch, setPitch] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [end, setEnd] = useState('');
  const [started, setStarted] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [videoData, setVideos] = useState([...videos]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({start: null, end: null});
  const [muted, setMuted] = useState(true);

  


 

 //Setting callbacks for the process status
  useEffect(() => {
   
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    return () => {
      //destroy the process after switching the screen
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);



  const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
    //Invoked when .start() is called without error
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
    setStarted('√');
  };

  const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
    setEnd('√');
  };

  const onSpeechError = (e) => {
    //Invoked when an error occurs.
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
    setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
  };

2. in this part we are matching the word sopken by the user and checking is if the same video is available in our data if it si then the video will come on the top

  const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer is finished recognizing
    console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e.value[0]);

    let vResult = e.value[0];
    let small = vResult.toLowerCase();

    setResults([small]);
    setShowModal(false);

    for (let i = 0; i < videoData.length - 1; i++) {
      let newArray = [...videos];
      if (small == newArray[i].name) {
        newArray.splice(0, 0, newArray[i]);

        const mainArray = newArray.filter((item, index) => {
          if (item.name == small && index != 0) {
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });

        setVideos(mainArray);
      }
    }
  };

  const startRecognizing = async () => {
    console.log('start listenind');
    //Starts listening for speech for a specific locale
    try {
      await Voice.start('en-US');
      setPitch('');
      setError('');
      setStarted('');
      setResults([]);
      setEnd('');
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
  const stopRecognizing = async () => {
    //Stops listening for speech
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

3. making video play n pause is out of axis

  onScroll = (event) => {
    const scrollPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const paused = paused;
    const {start, end} = position;
    if (scrollPosition < start && scrollPosition > end && paused) {
      setPaused(false);
    } else if (scrollPosition > start && scrollPosition < end && !paused) {
      setPaused(true);
    } else if (scrollPosition < end && !paused) {
      setPaused(true);
    }
  };

      4. getting the scroll y axis

        const threshold = 180;
        onVideoLayOut = (event) => {
        const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');
       const start = -(event.nativeEvent.layout.y - height + threshold);
       const end =
      event.nativeEvent.layout.y + event.nativeEvent.layout.height - threshold;
    // console.log(start, end, 'position');
         setPosition((state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        start: start,
        end: end,
      };
    });
    console.log(position, 'position1');
  };

5.this the render par using faltlist to render data     

          return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 70,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          marginHorizontal: 15,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginVertical: 15,
          marginTop: 25,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 40,
            borderRadius: 20,
            width: 300,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#F23C29',
          }}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search ..."
            style={{flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 30, color: 'white'}}
            placeholderTextColor="grey"
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              startRecognizing();
              setShowModal(true);
            }}>
            <SimpleLineIcons color={'white'} name="microphone" size={30} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderColor: 'orange',
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}>
        <FlatList
          data={videoData}
          // scrollEventThrottle={16}
          onScroll={onScroll}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            return (
              <View
                key={index}
                style={{
                  height: 250,
                  marginVertical: 20,
                }}>
                <Video
                  source={{uri: item.source}}
                  onLayout={onVideoLayOut}
                  muted={true}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  paused={!paused}
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: undefined,
                    aspectRatio: 2,
                    marginBottom: 200,
                    marginTop: 300,
                  }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    marginTop: 15,
                    color: 'white',
                  }}>
                  {item.title}
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
      {/* <ScrollView style={{flex: 2, width: '100%'}}>
        {videoData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <View
              key={index}
              style={{
                height: 250,
                marginVertical: 20,
              }}>
              <Video
                source={{uri: item.source}}
                paused={false}
                rate={1.0}
                volume={1.0}
                isMuted={false}
                resizeMode="contain"
                shouldPlay
                isLooping
                style={{width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: 2}}
                onError={(e) => {
                  console.log(e, 'video data');
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  marginTop: 15,
                  color: 'white',
                }}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView> */}
      <Modal
        visible={showModal}
        transparent={true}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setShowModal(false);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
          }}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="microphone-settings"
            size={45}
            color="white"
          />
          <Text
            style={{
              color: '#fff',
              textAlign: 'center',
              marginTop: 20,
              fontSize: 17,
            }}>
            We are listening
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      {/* <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Video</Text>
        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={stopRecognizing}
            style={styles.buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Stop</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={startRecognizing}>
            <SimpleLineIcons name="microphone" size={25} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        {results.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Text key={`result-${index}`} style={styles.textStyle}>
              {item}
            </Text>
          );`enter code here`
        })}
        <Text>Results</Text>
      </View> */}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

1. The question is in my flat list at a time, there are three videos which are render .. I was trying to make the first video play and rest to be in paused state and after a 5 second of interval, the next video should be played
2. I tried demo which looks like instagram where the video which is in focused is played automatically and rest all are paused
3. I tried using scroll props and also video-autoscroll lib but coudlnot resolve
4. the videos are getting render but

Comment: "the videos are getting render but" but what's the appearance?

Comment: bro the videos are rendering i just want to know how can i use contentoffset property to make the flat list get scrolled automatically using setinterval